# With ASP.NET, how can I pass a List inside of a Session to another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Right now I've got a custom object (BookList) that holds two lists inside of it, and that object is stored in a Session. How can I go about pulling just one of those lists out and using it in another page? I want to add that instance of the object stored in a Session to another list which contains only those specific lists... if that makes sense.

On the first page: 
BookList object (inside of which are two List objects, current and final)
A button which sends ONLY the 'final' List to the second page

On the second page:
Accepts ONLY the 'final' List from the first page, and adds it to a list of List objects - so a list of lists.

```
BookList books;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["booklists"] == null) {
        books = new BookList();
        Session.Add("booklists", books);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Session created.");
    } else {
        books = Session["booklists"] as BookList;
    }
```

And the BookList class...

```
public class BookList
{
    public List<Book> currentBooklist;
    public List<Book> finalBooklist;

    public BookList () {
        currentBooklist = new List<Book>();
        finalBooklist = new List<Book>();
    }

    public List<Book> getCurrentBooks() { return this.currentBooklist; }
    public List<Book> getFinalBooks()   { return this.finalBooklist; }
}
```

Comment: sorry a bit confused when you say stored in a session do you mean a session variable. and if so wouldn't a session variable be available to all pages?

Comment: Forget the only part. You're setting a name value pair collection. You can set anything in that session variable. The first page knows nothing about the second, and the second knows nothing about the first. All you can know is there is something in a session variable, or there isn't. You could put a booklist or a donkey in it. There's no way to force it to restrict what can be placed into the session variable.

Comment: Added the relevant code, hopefully it's more clear now. I wasn't aware that the Session variable was available to all pages, but would you still be able to get a specific variable WITHIN the object associated with the Session? 

For example, my Session is holding a BookList. But I want the List<Book> out of that BookList. Would I be able to get that specifically?

Comment: What is gained by encapsulating these 2 lists as one class? Maybe you should consider maintaining them as 2 separate objects, and then you would just let currentBookList die with the first page, while finalBooklist will get marshaled via the asp.net session collection.

Comment: You're exactly right about that. I initially kept them together to save some lines of code, but I'm realizing that it's probably better to keep them apart. Which solves the issue anyways.